# Error exit status 125 while trying to install quay mirror registry

Tags: openshift, mirroring

After downloading mirror-registry, when i am trying to install it, i am getting exit error code 125

This is the command that i am trying

```
./mirror-registry install
```

This is the error details that I am getting

```
   __   __
  /  \ /  \     ______   _    _     __   __   __
 / /\ / /\ \   /  __  \ | |  | |   /  \  \ \ / /
/ /  / /  \ \  | |  | | | |  | |  / /\ \  \   /
\ \  \ \  / /  | |__| | | |__| | / ____ \  | |
 \ \/ \ \/ /   \_  ___/  \____/ /_/    \_\ |_|
  \__/ \__/      \ \__
                  \___\ by Red Hat
 Build, Store, and Distribute your Containers
    
INFO[2023-07-07 11:27:57] Install has begun                            
INFO[2023-07-07 11:27:57] Found execution environment at /home/osboxes/demo-project/execution-environment.tar 
INFO[2023-07-07 11:27:57] Loading execution environment from execution-environment.tar 
ERRO[2023-07-07 11:27:58] An error occurred: exit status 125
```

Can please someone tell me what is the actual issue and how to fix it,

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```bash
./mirror-registry install -v
```

It should give you more information about your issue, mine was not enough space available:

```
[..]
Copying blob 9b17f51c8486 [=============================>--------] 676.1MiB / 867.3MiB
Error: writing blob: storing blob to file "/srv/container/.local/share/containers/cache/storage2779441453/1": write /srv/container/.local/share/containers/cache/storage2779441453/1: no space left on device
ERRO[2024-02-15 21:33:16] An error occurred: exit status 125
```